# Can I custom the notification area in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

Well, when you scroll down twice on Android Status Bar you see something similar to 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa65a.png)

I am trying to customize this zone. For example I would like to remove the Settings shortcut to not be able to access from this zone. I don't know how to do it, or if it is even possible.

I have thought of removing status bar and adding something who would always be waiting for the gesture to display something as I want. Am I looking at it the right way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It was only doable before Oreo when you could make a permanent floating view above status bar that would intercept the click & drag. Since then it's no longer possible because status and navigation bar will always appear on top. You will also get permanent notification with option to hide any floating views.

Comment: Thank you Pawel!
Could you tell me where is the documentation that specifies that it is no longer posible just to get a little deeper on this? I just can't find it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#cwt